# Python How to check if any value in a dictionary is None in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I have a dictionary dict_A.

It could be None, or it could be a dictionary where some key-values are None.

I need to check if dict_A is None or if any of the values in dict_A is None in a if statement to execute things differently.

```
if ( # if dict_A is None or if any of the values in dict_A is None ):
# do something
else:
# do something else
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the most pythonic way to do this, is

```
if (dict_A is None or None in dict_A.values()):
# do something
else:
# do something else
```

[Update]
Thank you for the comments below.

If I want to handle both None and {}, I could use

```
if ( not dict_A or None in dict_A.values()):
# do something
else:
# do something else
```

Comment: `dict_A.values()`, not `dict_A.values`

Comment: Can't the first check just be `if dict_A`?

Comment: @CutePoison it depends on how the OP wants to handle the case where `dict_A = {}`

Comment: @CutePoison, do you mean just using `if not dict_A` ?

Comment: in my case, the dict_A shall never be {}, but I think it's good to also handle {} just in case. Thank you for point that out.